# Unable to do telnet on websocket server

Tags: telnet, socket

My websocket server is running on port 9000 on an ec2 instance.
It's working perfectly when accessed through a browser.
But I am unable to do telnet to it.
I did **telnet ec2.x.y.z.com 9000** and the response is :
**telnet: connect to address 54.251.xx.yyz: Connection timed out**

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -an|grep -w 9000` on the server?

Comment: Are you trying from the same machine in both cases? Do you have some proxy server configured in your browser?

Comment: @Khaled. No, I am trying from different machines. No proxy server configured in the browser.

Comment: @MadHatter tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9000                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN

Comment: @Khaled It works if I do telnet from the same machine.

Comment: @dta: It seems that you have a firewall that is preventing you from accessing the server.

Comment: dta, if you're saying that **from a given host** when you visit the site on port 9000 by browser, or contact the machine on port 9000 by telnet, you get the same result, then your question is **fundamentally** flawed.  I agree with Khaled, that at the moment it looks much more likely that the machine that can't connect via telnet (or, presumably, by browser) is firewalled off in some way.

Comment: @Khaled Yes you are right. I was trying to do telnet through a HostMonster machine - which blocks outgoing connections to most of the ports. https://my.hostmonster.com/cgi/help/500. Can you put your answer separately - so that I can accept it.

Comment: @dta: posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the posted comments, it seems to me that you have a firewall that is preventing you from accessing the server. If so, you should not able to be access the server using the browser not only using telnet.